# Selenium - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking jsxSet_innerHTML

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium, HtmlUnitDriver with HtmlUnit Ver. 10.
I am getting the following stacktrace:

> ```
>   SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: Exception invoking jsxSet_innerHTML
> ======= EXCEPTION START ========
> Exception class=[com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException]
> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking jsxSet_innerHTML
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:594)
>     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
>     at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:544)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:519)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:927)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:53)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:101)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
>     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:153)
> ```

Source Code:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get(url);

try {
    Thread.sleep(10000L);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Am I missing anything over here.

Comment: Have you tried with different driver like FirefoxDriver?

Comment: Yes, I tried with FirefoxDriver and it works. But I need it to work  with HtmlUnitDriver as I want to run this script on the HeadLess Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DesiredCapabilities c = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

c.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

c.setBrowserName("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0");

WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(c);

driver.get(baseUrl);
```